# Trouble Understanding CPU Scheduling Concepts

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, cpu, scheduling

I have to write a CPU scheduling simulation with kernel level threads. I have to be able to use either first come first served (FCFS) or round robin (RR) algorithms. Data for the processes and their threads is given in the form of a text file. At the moment my program reads in the text file data into linked lists. I'm not really sure how to start the simulation (I've never programmed a simulation before).

Is this how I would proceed in the case of FCFS? When I get to the first thread of the first process, I add the cpu time to the clock time. Then do I simply add the io time to the clock as well while the cpu is idle? or should I put it back in a waiting queue and allow the next thread to start running in the cpu? If so how do I keep track of how much of each thread has already been excecuted?

here is an example test file:

```
2 4 6 // number_of_processes thread_switch process_switch
1 5 // process_number(1) number_of_threads(1)
1 0 4 // thread_number(1) arrival_time(1) number_of_CPU(1)
1 15 100 // 1 cpu_time io_time
2 18 120 // 2 cpu_time io_time
3 12 100 // 3 cpu_time io_time
4 16  // 4 cpu_time 
2 4 4 // thread_number(2) arrival_time(2) number_of_CPU(2)
1 18 110
2 15 80
3 20 75
4 15
3 6 5   //thread(3)
1 40 100
2 20 70
3 15 80
4 18 90
5 50
4 8 4   //thread(4) 
1 25 60
2 15 50
3 20 80
4 18  
5 18 4  //thread(5) 
1 8 60
2 15 120
3 12 80
4 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The I/O time seems ambiguous based upon the information provided.  Do you have a spec/instructions to go along with this?

In general I would think that the I/O time provides you with a window in which the currently executing thread(s) can be swapped out while they wait for I/O requests to complete.  Though nothing seems to indicate if the I/O time occurs before, after, or intermixed with the CPU time.  That may be a design decision you're expected to make when implementing your simulator.

There's also ambiguity with respect to what impact the 'number_of_CPU' option has.  How many CPU cores are you simulating?  Or is this just a count of the number of requests that the thread will make of the CPU (which it seems like it is, since you can't have a single thread running on multiple CPU's concurrently)?

In any case, you're correct about the general approach for handling the FCFS algorithm.  Essentially you'll want to maintain a queue of requests, and whenever the CPU is idle you simply pull the next thing out of the queue and execute it.   Assuming a single-core CPU and ignoring I/O time, the result should look something like this:

```
time=0
    Thread 1 arrives, and wants to do 15 time-units of work
        Thread 1 starts executing 15 time-units of work

time=4
    Thread 2 arrives, and wants to do 18 time-units of work
        Thread 2 is blocked because Thread 1 is executing

time=6
    Thread 3 arrives, and wants to do 40 time-units of work
        Thread 3 is blocked because Thread 1 is Executing

time=8
    Thread 4 arrives and wants to do 25 time-units of work
        Thread 4 is blocked because Thread 1 is Executing

time=15
    Thread 1 completes its initial set of work
    Thread 2 is next in the queue, and begins executing
    Thread 1 wants to do 18 time-units of work
        Thread 1 is blocked because Thread 2 is executing

time=18
    Thread 5 arrives and wants to do 8 time-units of work
        Thread 5 is blocked because Thread 2 is executing

time=33
    Thread 2 completes its initial set of work
    Thread 3 is next in the queue, and begins executing
    Thread 2 wants to do 15 time-units of work
        Thread 2 is blocked because Thread 3 is executing

...
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have specified that number_of_CPU is the number of CPU burst for that thread. Assuming that I am supposed to swap threads that are waiting for i/o (instead of ignoring io time), how would that change the output you posted?

Comment: Hard to say, though if the I/O time is front-loaded, than Thread 1 would immediately block/wait for 100 time-units at time=0.  Thread 2 would do a similar thing at time=4, and so on.  So in that case, the first thread to actually start executing would be Thread 4 (since it has the least I/O to do), at time=68.  Then at time=93, Thread 5 would go, since its I/O should also be done by then.  Assuming that I/O requests can execute concurrently/in parallel.  Otherwise, who knows?